# How to include example html code in a web page

Tags: html

When I want to write blog that is showing some sample code, I normally use the `<code>` element eg.

```
<pre>
  <code>
    some code here
    some more code
  </code>
</pre>
```

However this does not work if the sample code is html e.g.

```
<pre>
  <code>
    <div id="target"></div>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Doing this just produces a blank code block. How do I do this?

Comment: Your code `<div class="target></target>` is invalid for more than one reason. Correct it, and the HTML will be placed in the `<code>` block as expected. To actually get it to *display* the HTML, you need HTML entities.

Comment: #Obsidean Age, I have corrected the question, my actual code had the correct div syntax, and does not display the div as a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to replace the < and > brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

```
<pre>
  <code>
    &lt;div class="target"&gt;&lt;/target&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

Will render:

```
  
    <div class="target"></target>
```